# What is causing gnome-panel to crash and respawn constantly?

Tags: gnome-panel

hey everyone for some reason my gnome-panel keeps crashing and restarting and keeps shifting windows that I have open up and down as they reaccomodate for the crashing/respwaning gnome-panel. Prior to this I had the indicator global menu applet enabled and I opened a java program(freemind) and then this problem started happening. If I go into the terminal and type sudo gnome-panel --replace a new top and bottom panel gets created but in the window list I can still see a "starting panel" program opening and closing constantly. Does anyone know how I cold fix this?

Comment: You should file a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this, which will delete your panel settings and give you the defaults.

```
gconftool-2 --shutdown
rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel
pkill gnome-panel
```

You don't want to run `sudo gnome-panel --replace`. That creates a panel as the root user (note the username in the panel is "root"), but your own panel is still continuing to crash in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this commands a try to reset the panel to default values:

`gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/panel`

`pkill gnome-panel`

Also, make sure that you (and not root) are still the owner of all files under $HOME/.gconf/apps/panel/ (which may occur after using sudo gnome-panel)